# Value type and reference type with c#.NET code sample?

Tags: c#

Here is the code sample that one of the interviewer asked:

```
void fool1(string arg)
{
   arg = arg + " ABCD";
}


void fool2(ref string arg)
{
   arg = arg + " ABCD";
}


string fool3(string arg)
{
   return arg = arg + " ABCD";
}
```

What is the value of arg from Console.app from these 3 methods?

Comment: Why can you not just create a console application and try all 3? What makes our copies of visual studio magical and yours not?

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with value types and reference types. Passing parameters by value or by reference isn't the same thing.

Comment: This looks like homework to me - well ok, an interview question.

Comment: I think she has no internet and no Visual Studio and is posting from cybercafe after failing the interview.

Comment: Exactly. Interviewer told my answer was wrong. That's why posting here.

Comment: Interestingly I answered all complicated questions... He told my answer to this basic question was wrong.

Comment: Any place that asks such idiotic interview questions is not worth working for. I bet the interviewer googled the question before taking taking the interview to appear smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fool1` doesn't change the `args` variable from the calling method. It only changes it inside the `fool` method (so the reference changes).

```
string a = "x";
fool1(a);
// a is still "x"
```

Function `fool2` DOES change the `args` variable from the calling method.

```
string a = "x";
fool2(ref a);
// a is "xABCD"
```

Function `fool3` doesn't change the `args` variable from the calling method.

```
string a = "x";
string b = fool3(a);
// a is "x", b is "xABCD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just test it yourself to see what happens; then try to understand *why* it happens. **That’s** what the interviewer is interested in.

```
string someString = "Foo";

fool1(someString);
Console.WriteLine(someString); // Foo

fool2(ref someString);
Console.WriteLine(someString); // Foo ABCD

fool3(someString);
Console.WriteLine(someString); // Foo ABCD

someString = fool3(someString);
Console.WriteLine(someString); // Foo ABCD
```